# Как с помощью jQuery ( или правильно ) заносить в массив данные переменной 'valCookie'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Мне необходимо в массив 'indArray[];' заносить значения переменной 'valCookie' - т.е. индексы по клику, что бы массив хранил куки и состояние меню сохранялось при переходе по ссылкам.  Как мне реализовать грамотный занос данных переменной в массив ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {


//index array
    var indArray = [];
    var indToCookie;
    var valCookie;


// take index click element

    $('ul > li  > span').click(function() {
    indToCookie = $('ul > li > span').index(this); 
    $.cookie('nav-item', indToCookie);
    valCookie = $.cookie('nav-item');
});


 $('ul.list-1 > li > span').click(function() {
  $("ul.list-1 ul").toggleClass('active');
});

 });
```

Comment: indArray.push(сюда "грамотный занос данных переменной")

Comment: т.е.  indArray.push(valCookie);?

Comment: если в valCookie хранится конечная переменная которую необходимо запоминать, то все верно

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что Вам нужно это

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  //index array
  let indArray = [];
  let indToCookie;
  let valCookie;


  // take index click element

  $("ul > li  > span").on("click", ()=> {
    indToCookie = $("ul > li > span").index(this); 
    $.cookie("nav-item", indToCookie);
    indArray.push(indToCookie );
  });


  $("ul.list-1 > li > span").on("click", ()=> {
    $("ul.list-1 ul").toggleClass("active");
  });

});
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, а что означают данные символы кода " ()=> " ??